# correct use of promise

Tags: jquery, ajax, typescript, promise, deferred

I have a separate typescript file which I use that contains only my ajax calls.

I have a second typescript file that I am using to load up a knockout observable array

Finally I have a view that calls the knockout object and then attempts to bind the data to a drop down.

This is my ajax data call

```
export class ILRDataService {
    public dataServiceOptions: DataServiceOptions;
    public getPeriodsForCandidate() {
        var urlToUse = this.dataServiceOptions.baseUrl + 'ilrdata/' +
            this.dataServiceOptions.periodIdentifier +
            '/AcademicPeriods/' + this.dataServiceOptions.candidateIdentifier;
        return $.ajax({
            url: urlToUse
        });
    }
}
```

This is called from my class. This is the method that calls the getPeriodsForCandidate method

```
export class AcademicPeriod {
    private dataServiceOptions: DataServiceOptions;
    public LoadPeriodsForCandidate() {
        var self = this;
        var dataService = new Ilr.ILRDataService(self.dataServiceOptions);
        return dataService.getPeriodsForCandidate()
            .done(function (academicPeriods) {
                $.each(academicPeriods, function (index, element) {
                    self.Items.push(element);
                    console.log(element);
                });
            });
    }
}
```

And finally on my view I have the following code

```
var academicPeriodsViewModel = new Ilr.AcademicPeriod(dataServiceOptions);
$.when(academicPeriodsViewModel.LoadPeriodsForCandidate())
    .then(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(academicPeriodsViewModel, document.getElementById("AcademicPeriods"));
});
```

My problem is in the LoadPeriodsForCandidate method of the AcademicPeriod period, the function is returning immediately, not after processing the $.each, and is causing the binding to failing in Internet Explorer.

The binding does not fail everytime. If I have the F12 developer tools open, then the binding works. But if the F12 dev tool window is closed, then the binding frequently fails. I cant see the failure message because I need to F12 window open to view the console, and the minute that happens, everything works.

No problems using the above code in Chrome or Firefox.

I have tested, and if I create a new callback function and alter my code as the following:

```
public LoadPeriodsForCandidate(callbackFunction) {
    var self = this;
    var dataService = new Ilr.ILRDataService(self.dataServiceOptions);
    dataService.getPeriodsForCandidate()
        .done(function (academicPeriods) {
            $.each(academicPeriods, function (index, element) {
                self.Items.push(element);
            });
            callbackFunction();
        });
    }
```

and change the code on my view to the following:

```
academicPeriodsViewModel.LoadPeriodsForCandidate(bindAcademicPeriods);
function bindAcademicPeriods() {
    ko.applyBindings(academicPeriodsViewModel, document.getElementById("AcademicPeriods"));
}
```

Then everything works in IE

However I think that this is more of a kludge, and want to know how / what I need to do to change the method LoadPeriodsForCandidate so that I can successfully using the $.when().then() correctly

Comment: What is a " typescript file"?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot View this website. http://www.typescriptlang.org/ It will describe what typescript is better than I can.

Comment: Darren, thank you for the link. As it seems relevant, should the question be tagged "typescript"? The tag certainly exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.then()` instead of `.done()` in the function.

Calling `.then()` will return a new promise that waits for the callback (and any promise that it returns) to finish.

Note that you don't need to call `$.when()`.

Comment: I modified LoadPeriodsForCandidate so that the .done is now using .then 
I also removed the $.when from so that I just now call
academicPeriodsViewModel.LoadPeriodsForCandidate()
                        .then(function() {
                            ko.applyBindings(academicPeriodsViewModel, document.getElementById("AcademicPeriods"));
                        });
      
Unfortunately It is still not binding in IE

Comment: @DarrenGuy: IE does not define a `console` object if the dev tools are closed, so you're getting a runtime error.  Remove all console calls.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the console.log statement, and now it appears that IE is playing nicely. I would like to understand why is the console.log command throwing an error in IE?

Comment: @DarrenGuy: In IE, there is no `console` object when the dev tools are not opened.   You were therefore getting a `console is undefined` error.